# how to pass the arguments having special characters from one jsp page to other jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

I have the below code in the jsp.

```
<%
String po = request.getParameter("PO");
String mo = request.getParameter("MO");
String ao = request.getParameter("AO");
String op = request.getParameter("OP");

String args = "PO="+polno;
args += "&MO="+mo;
args += "&AO="+ao;
args += "&OP="+op;  //here the value of the op is S#M.
%>

<HTML>
<FRAME SRC="<%=root%>/cso/PoCommentsForm.jsp?<%=args%> NAME="PoCommForm" >
</HTML>
```

In the above code while passing the args(arguments) to jsp page in Frame the op value S#M, is being truncated after # and it is taking value as S only.
How to pass the remaining value along with # as S#M in the args without being truncated.

Kindly let me know if something is weird.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [URL-encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) each parameter:

```
String op = URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("OP"), "UTF-8");
```

Alternatively, you may be able to pass the entire original [query string](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29):

```
<FRAME SRC="<%=root%>/cso/PoCommentsForm.jsp?${request.queryString} NAME="PoCommForm" >
```